# Can someone tell me where De Morgan's law is used in real life, it is really confusing to understand it with a real life scenario

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have been trying to apply De morgan's law in Logic gates, and realized I am not quite sure if I can use it on my own if given a random problem, which clearly means I dont understand it or connect to it in real life. So could anyone explain, where it is used in a real-life scenario, and also why it is used, and where and when we can use them.

for example : (A and B)' = A' OR B' , I mean how do I connect this in real life?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   If it is not true that Jack is in the room and Jill is in the room, then Jack is not in the room or Jill is not in the room

Comment: LOL, there ! I just dont see how I can get convinced with that. could you explain

Comment: Literally anywhere logical statements appear, DeMorgan's Laws often appear.

Comment: How about a picture proof then... See http://guideocom.blogspot.com/2011/08/de-morgans-laws-venn-diagrams-proofs.html

Comment: umm, its an honest math question, why the downvote though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say there's some number $x$ you care about but the exact value of which you don't know. Now I tell you that $x$ is **not** a prime greater than $42$.

Then you know that EITHER $x$ is not prime, OR $x$ is not greater than $42$ *(or perhaps both!)*. This is an instance of the law $$\neg (A\wedge B)\quad\equiv\quad (\neg A)\vee (\neg B)$$ (here $A$ is "$x$ is a prime number" and $B$ is "$x$ is greater than $42$"). In general, we can use rules like this to break down complicated properties ("prime greater than $42$") in ways which may make them easier to reason about (e.g. we can try to prove things about $x$ by cases, handling the $\neg A$-case and the $\neg B$-case separately).

Comment: The way you explained it as well as the example you used is surely going to confuse him more, but I took it back.

Comment: @DerekLuna Why do you think so? (I can always change it if I'm convinced, after all.)

Comment: I think there are much clearer examples to use such as in room/not in room or boy/girl than to use what you did here. He also asked for a real life example :p.

Comment: OH maaan @NoahSchweber this example blew my friggin mind, but i believe the example is not complete, we cant find x with those constraints, could you complete the question, I am halfway there understanding the problem, i believe

Comment: @HariShankarRavindran "we cant find x with those constraints" That's true - often in math, and in life in general, we reason with *partial information*. Logical rules help us do this. The fact that in this example you're not able to figure out what exactly $x$ is doesn't affect the fact that you *can* figure some things out - and in particular, apply the law above.

Comment: @DerekLuna That's fair. I'm tentatively of the opposite opinion, actually: in my experience, such sentences tend to sound a bit off (e.g. nobody actually says "it is not the case that both Sam and Max are in the living room"), and this lends a bit of a confusing flavor to things. Paradoxically, I've found - for some people at least - that a little bit of math can actually make things clearer, since we tend to have fewer expectations about what sorts of abstract statements we'll run into. (And who says math isn't part of real life? :P)

Comment: @NoahSchweber could you share a complete question like finding a number, in some given series using de morgan's law.

Comment: @HariShankarRavindran Since the conclusion of this particular law is a **disjunction**, not really: the rule here lets you conclude OR-statements. This doesn't mean that this rule can't be used *in the process* of figuring some particular fact out, but that's not the right way to think of it *on its own* - you should think of the rule as taking some stuff we know, maybe not everything we want to know, and rephrasing it in a hopefully-easier-to-use way.

Comment: so where is it really used to implement though ?

Comment: @HariShankarRavindran Well, it can be an important step in a proof by cases. Maybe I have some statement $C$ I want to prove from the hypothesis $\neg (A\wedge B)$. Then De Morgan's law tells me that it's enough to do two "smaller" tasks: prove $C$ from $\neg A$, and then prove $C$ from $\neg B$. Note that both $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ are "simpler" than our original $\neg(A\wedge B)$; the hope is basically that because of this they'll be easier to work with.

Comment: That may seem a bit abstract, but that's going to be hard to avoid. Rules like De Morgan are used for manipulating *complicated logical forms*, and in natural language we tend to avoid those - for instance, sentences like "It is not the case that both Sam and Max are in the living room" generally sound a little odd.

Comment: So lets say, I am doing an ad campaign, for two users A and B, one likes shoes and hat, the other likes shoes, so I have a shoe company and a hat company approaching me to run an ad campaign, how can I arrive at a conclusion ? I am just trying to relate it somehow to find a solution to a real world scenario, you are free to demonstrate the law with something similar to this too

Comment: @HariShankarRavindran "how can I arrive at a conclusion?" What does a conclusion even look like in the example you're describing? What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve, there? I *really* don't think it's a good idea to try to understand these laws as working towards a conclusion; they're just ways of taking complicated statements and rephrasing them in hopefully-less-complicated ways.

Comment: well , I believe we can. The example that I gave was to decide for which user I should send the ad of which product. And to derive a conclusion , we want to build an OR gate using only three NAND(compliment of AND is NAND) gates with two inputs A and B. that is, two A inputs to NAND and two B inputs to 2nd NAND, passing the 2 outcomes as the input of the 3rd NAND , we get an OR gate. this is achieved by implementing De Morgan's law , so how do I think of this law when situatuons like this arise, I am not able to connect @NoahSchweber

Comment: @HariShankarRavindran I stand by my previous comment. That said, you can always un-accept this answer and accept a different one (maybe paw88789's, which you seem to like) if you find it more helpful - just click the currently-green checkmark on mine.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I already did :) Your approach of finding the number using demorgan's law helped me connect the dots, so. Thank you. I ll go ahead and research with what I have ! cheers

Comment: @HariShankarRavindran Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

They're baked into the English language. Consider the statements

> 1. I don't own a car and I don't own a bicycle.
> 2. I don't own a car or a bicycle.
> 3. I don't own a car and a bicycle.

The first two express the same idea, and are of the forms $\neg A \land \neg B$ and $\neg(A\lor B)$ respectively. This equivalence is one of De Morgan's laws.

The third statement is of the form $\neg (A\land B)$ and isn't equivalent to the first two, as it's possible I don't own a bicycle but do own a car (or vice versa) in addition to the possibility of owning neither. What I just wrote out is $\neg A\lor\neg B$, and De Morgan's law correctly states that it is equivalent to $\neg (A\land B)$

Comment: Thank you ! this helps too

Answer (score 0):

$(A$ and $B$)' means that it is not the case that we have both $A$ and $B$. So it must be the case that we don't have one of those which means either we don't have $A$ or we don't have $B$.

If it is not the case that $A$ and $B$ are both boys, then at least one of them must be a girl.

Answer (score 0):

De Morgan's laws with sets.

$$x \notin A\cap B$$
means that
$$x \notin A \text{ or } x\notin B$$

and

$$x\notin A\cup B$$
means
$$x \notin A \text{ and } x\notin B.$$

If a country is not a permanent member of the security council, then it is not France, and it is not USA and it is not China and it is not Russia and it is not UK.

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't go to Boston or I didn't go to Chicago" means I didn't go to both Boston and Chicago (though I might have gone to one of them).  That is $\neg(B)\vee \neg(C)\equiv \neg(B\wedge C)$

"I don't like spiders and I don't like cockroaches" means I like neither spiders nor cockroaches.  That is $\neg S \wedge \neg C \equiv \neg(S\vee C)$

Comment: NICE ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I am trying to diet, and decide that I cannot have both a burger *and* fries for dinner. Well, then whatever I end up eating, I either won't have a burger, or I won't have fries (or maybe I have neither)